# Not able to connect to maas 2.x with landscape

Tags: maas, landscape

I am wondering if there is support for maas 2.x in landscape. I keep getting 401 gone when trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Landscape 17.03 support for both MAAS 2.x and Juju 2.x is available. The easiest way to get started is:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up landscape
```